# MySQL error 6400 (42000) check the manual corresponds to your Mysql server version

Tags: mysql

this is my table:

```
mysql> create table medication(
        mid int (11) not null auto_increment  primary key, 
        tid varchar(255) not null,
        titname varchar(255) not null,
        minvalue varchar(255) not null, 
        maxvalue varchar(255) not null,
        disc varchar(255) not null, 
        tanem varchar(255) default null);
```

here is the error

Error 1064 (42000): you have an error in you SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to you MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'maxvalue varchar(255) not null, disc varchar(255) not null, tname varchar(255) d ' at line 1

My sql version is : 5.6.19 - win 32
os: windows 7, 64bit

Other table are saved successfully with almost same pattern. but for this table only showing error.

Help me, thank you.

Comment: The DDL looks good, I just tested and it works !!

Comment: There could be some unicode char (which is indistinguishable by human eyes) in the text, what you can do to diagnostic is try to use `#` to comment out some of the lines to see up to which point you have the error.

Answer (score 1):

`maxvalue` is a reserved keyword in mysql

```
mysql> create table medication(
        mid int not null auto_increment  primary key, 
        tid varchar(255) not null,
        titname varchar(255) not null,
        minvalue varchar(255) not null, 
        `maxvalue` varchar(255) not null,
        disc varchar(255) not null, 
        tanem varchar(255) default null);
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbca2c)

Comment: @user3755094 can you check SQL fiddle

Comment: the same one which i mention above

Comment: have you used  backticks for maxvalue??

Answer (score 0):

`maxvalue` is reserve key word in mysql. Check [Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) for Reserve word.

```
create table `medication`(
`mid` int (11) not null auto_increment  primary key, 
`tid` varchar(255) not null,
`titname` varchar(255) not null,
`minvalue` varchar(255) not null, 
`maxvalue` varchar(255) not null,
`disc` varchar(255) not null, 
`tanem` varchar(255) default null);
```

Comment: Always habbit to write fieldname and table name in back ticks

Comment: yes maxvalue is a reserved keyword, so how can i declare that key word? still im getting problem after enter the table as u given.

Comment: ok i got it by changing the "maxvalue" into "maxivalue".  but cant i use the "maxvalue" and execute?

Comment: Yes you can use maxvalue but remember using back ticks like `maxvalue` can you give me your create table query which have you tried now?

Comment: Have you got your solution?

Comment: i have given back "ticks for maxvalue" but it dint take.

Comment: so i just changed it to maxivalue then it takes,

Comment: Just you have to simply copy and paste my code it will work fine